# Which maven plugin I can use to download files from any online repository?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want to download tar.gz files from svn repository. This files are packaged by other maven projects and I want to package them as part of my project.

I know using wget we can do that but I don't know the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [maven-wagon-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) which supports such things.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>download-test-data</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>download</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>atlassian-public</serverId>
          <url>http://WhatEverURL/</url>
          <fromDir>WhatEverFolder/xyz.tar.gz</fromDir>
          <toDir>${project.build.directory}/download/</toDir>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

To download only a single file you can use the [download-single](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/download-single-mojo.html) goal.

Comment: Thanks much..It really solved my problem.But you may be knowing that wagon plugin with goal as download throws exception saying that it must implement getFilesFromList() method. My purpose was to get single file only so I used download-single goal..Anyway thanks much :)

Comment: Sorry you need to go for [download-single](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/download-single-mojo.html) instead.